# Getting SyntaxError: Name argument is not a valid custom element name

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, syntax-error, enzyme, custom-element

I am trying to do unit testing of my React app using Enzyme with Jest but getting this error

` FAIL  src/components/XYZ/**tests**/ABC.test.js

● Test suite failed to run

```
SyntaxError: Name argument is not a valid custom element name.
```

Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.224 s
Ran all test suites.`

My Jest Config file is as following

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "d3": "<rootDir>/node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./src/"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/setUpTests.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./node_modules/"
    ]
  },
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here ? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the configuration used for setupFiles is wrong here. As per jest documentation

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array

setUpFiles is used for "A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment. Each setupFile will be run once per test file. Since every test runs in its own environment, these scripts will be executed in the testing environment before executing setupFilesAfterEnv and before the test code itself. "

Please either remove setUpFiles or use proper file path here .